# The intersection 'x & y' was reduced to 'never' because property 'Z' has conflicting types in some constituents

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to render a component based on a key of that component in the (MODES) array. I want to render the component that its key is equal to the mode that is passed as prop . I have already read related questions but did not get so much . by the way it is my first question sorry if it is not so clear ! here is my code

the react component

```
import {infoPresenterProps} from "types/components/info-presenter/infoPresenter.type";
import MovieInfoMode from "components/info-presenter/modes/movie/MovieInfoMode";
import PlaylistInfoMode from "components/info-presenter/modes/playlist/PlaylistInfoMode";


const MODES = [
    {
        key: "movie",
        Component: MovieInfoMode
    },
    {
        key: "playlist",
        Component: PlaylistInfoMode
    }
]
export default function InfoPresenter({mode, data}: infoPresenterProps) {
    const index = MODES.findIndex(item => item.key === mode);
    const {Component} = MODES[index];

    return (
        <Component data={data}/>
    );
}
```

types that I am using :

```
export type movieModeDataType = {
    image: string,
    name: string,
    quality: string,
    rate: string,
    genre: string [],
}
export type playlistModeDataType = {
    name: string,
    image?: never,
    quality?: never,
    rate?: never,
    genre?: never
}
type infoPresenterMovieModeProps = {
    mode: "movie"
    data: movieModeDataType
}
type infoPresenterPlaylistModeProps = {
    mode: "playlist"
    data: playlistModeDataType
}
export type infoPresenterProps = infoPresenterMovieModeProps |
    infoPresenterPlaylistModeProps;
```

the error occurs when I wanna pass the (data) prop to the (Component) in the return section and it says :

*The intersection 'movieModeDataType & playlistModeDataType' was reduced to 'never' because property 'image' has conflicting types in some constituents.Type 'movieModeDataType' is not assignable to type 'never'.*

Thanks

Comment: This works for me... https://codepen.io/adiutankt72/pen/abYYYKM . Probably you should show those components too...

Comment: Please provide a [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE that demonstrates what you're seeing.  Please consider changing your example code's type names to follow UpperPascalCase naming conventions (e.g., `InfoPresenterMovieModeProps` instead of `infoPresenterMovieModeProps`).